# Looking for a library for encoding/decoding MPEG-2

Tags: c#, .net, mpeg

Can someone recommend to me a good .NET library that can encode and decode MPEG-2 files? If the library can make VOBs for DVD movies, that'd be a plus. I'm looking for something C# specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider the library at the following link:
http://nolovelust.com/post/Another-Simple-C-Wrapper-For-FFmpeg.aspx

Open FFMPEG is a library that has been around for quite some time.

The project at the link mentioned seems to have done what you seek.

You can download the source files from:
http://www.mediafire.com/?z7t7uqztp871xm7

I checked the download link. It works.